# Running powershell command in NSIS throws Access to the path has been denied

Tags: powershell, nsis

We need to run a powershell comman in our NSIS installer. Running the command in the powershell is no problem and running the command with

```
'powershell.exe "& "our command here"'
```

in the windows command line is no problem either. If we use the PowerShellExec Macro

```
${PowerShellExec} "our command"
```

or if we use the NSexec command does not matter. We always get the error message that "The access to the path has been denied". We found out that it might be a problem with the security policy of the powershell. Is there a way to change the security policy in NSIS or is there another way to call the command inside the installer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're testing on systems that only have PowerShell v2 installed, this appears to be a [known issue](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/PowerShell_support) with [PowerShell v2](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/572313/powershell-exe-can-hang-if-stdin-is-redirected).

There are several workarounds mentioned in both the Nullsoft forum and on MS Connect.  The most straightforward solution is to add `-InputFormat None` to the command line, but that is undocumented.

Alternately, if it's the execution policy that's throwing you, you can try adding `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the command line.